# MSP430F6638 stack problem

Tags: msp430

I'm programming a MSP430f6638 via JTAG interface, specifically i'm using TS430PZ100USB kit, and I'm trying to write a FAT16 file in an SDCard so I'm using the FatFs modules to make the system file, the thing is that this module has a couple nested functions, so when i initialize the project i realize the stack has reached its full capacity which (according to IAR Workbench) is only 160 bytes long, when I check the datasheet I can't find exactly the capacity of the stack but RAM is 16kB long, is divided in four sections of 4kB so the top section should be the one where I can find the stack, I don't think an MSP430 has such a small stack, this a common enough high level application. If anyone could give me an answer.

Comment: Stack size is set in the .xcl file. Have you tried changing it?

Comment: Thanks, i just found the .xcl, i did'nt know i couls do so, i'll give it a try, i hope that works

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very general with respect to these devices, I have more experience with the 8051, which also has a very small stack (128 or 256 bytes). I would always write the code with a maximum of only 1 deep into the call stack. Is it possible for you to re-write your code to accomplish this? The compiler can try and inline your call stack, but this doesn't always work.

Comment: That is not possible with a reasonable and maintainable FAT implementation. Its just too complex.